# Scala: to put constraints on the fields of a class

Tags: scala, constraints, field

In Scala how to put constraints on the fields of a class?
In a package I have the domain of my model, in another package I have dsl to instantiate my model.
The basic form of the model is this:

```
abstract class Element {
  var name: String
  var description: String
  var types : Set[Type]  
}

class SAComponent (var name :String,
        var description : String,
        var properties : Set[Property] = Set(),
        var types : Set[Type] = Set(),
        ) extends Component
```

Element is the root of my model.
I want to put constraints on the fields of Element, so that each class that inherits name and description and types of Element respects these constraints.
In other words **I need to define the I get for these fields.** Right?
How should I do?

I tried that, but the constraints are not respected:

```
abstract class Element {    
  def name: String
  def name_= (value: String): Unit = {if (isBadValue(value)throw new IllegalArgumentException
  name = value
  }
  var description : String,
  var types : Set[Type] = Set }

  class Component (override var name : String, var description: String) extends Element
```

The problem is that some fields that must respect the constraints,
in the constructor of the concrete classes must be initialized to a null value. So the "*require*" for me is not a good solution.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Checking at initialization does not work for you because you want stateful objects, which can be avoided by using case classes. Instead of mutating the state of an object, you may want to create new objects using `copy(field=value)`, which is automatically generated for case classes.

If you still want to go with stateful objects, I guess you want something like

```
abstract class Element {    
  private var _name: String = null
  def name_= (value: String) {
    require(!isBadValue(value),"Bad Value")
    _name = value
  }
  def name = _name
  def isBadValue(value: String): Boolean
}
class Component (initialName : String) extends Element {
  name = initialName
  def isBadValue(value: String) = value=="name"
}
val c = new Component(null)  // works
c.name = "name"              // exception
```

Another thing to point out: the setter generated by `override var name` in your code overrides your `name_=` method, which you may already know.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract val:

```
trait Init {
  val name: String
  require(!isBadName(name))
  def isBadName(name: String) = true
}
```

Creation:

```
new { val name = "init" } with Init
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
But your solution does not work for me.
I need "var" and not val.
And control must be done every time you change the value, not only when you instance the first time.
You have any suggestions?